# React-Native : Setting up Android emulator, JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: android, react-native

I get this error. (I know this might not be React native specific and i also tried other solutions i still don't come right.)

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: ”/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home”
```

I just installed jdk 8, This is how i did the export.

```
export JAVA_HOME=”$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)”
```

And added to ~/.profile

```
vi ~/.profile, //then added : export JAVA_HOME=”$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)”
```

Below is the error i get whe i run *react-native run-android*

[image]

Comment: maybe using straight `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)`

Comment: Thanks, This worked. No i am getting 

    `SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.`

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you execute `which java` from your command line?

On my machine I get `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

and it is because I have exported my JAVA HOME as follows:
`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home`

and then I have : 
`export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}` to make sure that this JAVA_HOME is set before the system's.

Comment: @Lino solution worked, however i'm now getting.
 `SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.`